# Alpine Linux 3.12.0 -> NFSMount failing due to rpc.statd not starting

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I have searched quite a bit and have found similar issues but none with fixes that are seeming to work for me.

I'm running an Alpine LXC on Proxmox. It is a privileged containers and NFS Mounts are enabled.

I am able to manually mount my NFS share via the mount command. I have since added the mount to my /etc/fstab and that's working, except on reboots.

I read that I needed to start / enable the nfsmount service to handle that on boot. However, when attempting to enable that service I'm met with the following.

```
 * Starting NFS statd ...
 * start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/usr/sbin/rpc.statd'                                                                                                         [ !! ]
 * ERROR: rpc.statd failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start nfsmount as rpc.statd would not start
```

Checking the /usr/sbin directory shows that there is no rpc.statd. The repo for Alpine shows that it should be brought in when nfs-utils is installed, the other rpc directories are.

I added the repo for a previous Alpine version and installed a rolled back nfs-utils. This successfully supplies me with the rpc.statd file in /usr/sbin but still fails to start.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't solve the root problem, nfsmount still won't launch.

However for anyone looking for a way to automount NFS shares within a LXC Container I do have a solution.

I first tried adding a script to the if-up.d location but it seems that LXC containers don't launch all of the init sections that a typical installation would.

My solution was to enable the local.d service with rc-update add local default

Then I placed a file in /etc/local.d/ called 'fstab.local' as a bash script that calls the mount -a option after checking if the network interface is up.

Answer (score 0):

Reply a bit dated, but applicable.

To be able to startup NFS automatically, Alpine needs "file capabilities" which are dropped by default in the /usr/share/lxc/config/alpine.common.conf file.

```
lxc.cap.drop = setpcap
```

See `man capabilities` for an explanation of the capabilities bits.
There are a couple of ways to fix this, you can update the alpine.common.conf file commenting out the line above (my choice since most of my alpine containers use NFS), but beware that an update will reset it, so you'll have to remember to check/change the file after updating, or you can modify the individual containers .conf file, which should be found at /etc/pve/lxc/####.conf where #### is the container id.
You need to reset the capabilities then re-drop capabilities as per the common and alpine configurations.  I used the following to do this when I did the individual files, it was stored as /usr/local/bin/alpine-enable-nfs.sh on my system, so I could type `alpine-enable-nsf.sh 1492` and container 1492 would have the capabilities set to allow NFS:

```
#!/bin/bash
defdir=/usr/share/lxc/config
cfile=/etc/pve/lxc/${1}.conf
if [ ! -r ${cfile} ] ; then
  echo "usage: ${0##*/} IDNO"
  exit
fi
if grep -q "lxc.cap.drop" ${cfile} ; then
  echo "File has lxc.cap.drop configurations already"
  exit
fi
if ! grep -q "ostype: alpine" ${cfile} ; then
  echo "Container ID: ${1} is not alpine."
  exit
fi
echo "# Reset capabilities" >> ${cfile}
echo "lxc.cap.drop:" >> ${cfile}
grep cap ${defdir}/common.conf >> ${cfile}
sed -n "/cap/{/setpcap/s/^/#/;p}" ${defdir}/alpine.common.conf >> ${cfile}
grep cap ${cfile}
echo -e "\nNFS should now be available in container #${1}"
```

As of writing, this should add the following to your container config:

```
# Reset capabilities
lxc.cap.drop:
# Drop some harmful capabilities
lxc.cap.drop = mac_admin mac_override sys_time sys_module sys_rawio
# Drop another (potentially) harmful capabilities.
lxc.cap.drop = audit_write
lxc.cap.drop = ipc_owner
lxc.cap.drop = mknod
#lxc.cap.drop = setpcap
lxc.cap.drop = sys_nice
lxc.cap.drop = sys_pacct
lxc.cap.drop = sys_rawio
lxc.cap.drop = sys_resource
lxc.cap.drop = sys_tty_config
lxc.cap.drop = syslog
lxc.cap.drop = wake_alarm
```

Note that the setpcap line is commented out (# at start)

You'll need to STOP and START your containers for this to take effect (rebooting a container won't pick up the change, it must be stopped then started again)

Some people suggest the "right" way to do things is to mount the NFS share in the host, but for me that is problematic as I have a couple dozen alpine containers that all mount different NFS shares from a few different servers for various uses, including some not available directly to the host, hence this approach.